# CAST numeric to varchar is giving scientific notation

Tags: casting, sql-server-2012, type-conversion, concatenation

I have three fields that I am trying to concatenate into one large field.  Two of the fields are varchar, but one is a float.  In certain situations, the concatenated field is showing scientific notation.  The concatenated field should be a varchar and show the combination of the three fields regardless of how they are formatted.  I am even seeing scientific notation when I just concatenate the two varchar fields when the values have all numbers in them.  Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?  Here are some examples of ways I am trying to do the concatenation:

```
Field1 = e.DocumentNo + e.Assignment + CAST(CAST([Amount in LC] as int) as nvarchar(50))

Field2 = CAST(e.DocumentNo + e.Assignment as varchar(255))
```

I have also tried using CONVERT and it does not provide the expected result.  DocumentNo is a varchar(255) and Assignment is a varchar(255), yet when I have these values for each, 5115146916 and 1610000 respectively, Field2 looks like 5.11515E+16.

I also tried to use CONCAT() with the fields and it produces the same undesired result.

Comment: @tsqln00b I can't recreate this based on what I understand of the above.. can you build a SQL Fiddle with sample data?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6d02/7/0

Comment: This works for anything where the Amount in LC field is not over 6 digits.  CONCAT(DocumentNo,Assignment,[Amount in LC])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#ConcatData','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ConcatData;

CREATE TABLE #ConcatData(
[Amount in LC] [float] NULL,
[Assignment] [varchar](255) NULL,
[DocumentNo] [varchar](255) NULL)

INSERT INTO #ConcatData
VALUES
(-27.08, '20120295', '4820110172'),
(10625451.5124, '20140701', '4810122475'),
(205.5, 'TPE035948900001', '8200022827'),
(10000000, 'TPE035948900001', '8200022827')

SELECT DOCUMENTNO + 
       ASSIGNMENT +
       CASE WHEN RIGHT(str([amount in lc],50,4),4) = '0000'
                THEN ltrim(LEFT(str([amount in lc],50,4),LEN(str([amount in lc],50,4))-5))
            WHEN RIGHT(str([amount in lc],50,4),3) = '000'
                THEN ltrim(LEFT(str([amount in lc],50,4),LEN(str([amount in lc],50,4))-3))
            WHEN RIGHT(str([amount in lc],50,4),2) = '00'
                THEN ltrim(LEFT(str([amount in lc],50,4),LEN(str([amount in lc],50,4))-2))
            WHEN RIGHT(str([amount in lc],50,4),1) = '0'
                THEN ltrim(LEFT(str([amount in lc],50,4),LEN(str([amount in lc],50,4))-1))
            ELSE ltrim(str([amount in lc],50,4))
            END
FROM #ConcatData
```

Moral of the story here, `float` isn't the right datatype for your column.  I actually don't know when `float` is the right datatype...

Anyway, the obnoxious `CASE` statement is needed to remove excess decimal-place zeroes caused by `STR()`.  You might even need more, but this covers you up to 4 decimal places and I think you'll get the idea.

One note, the first `THEN` removes 5 chars instead of 4.  This is to include the `.` as well.

Output:

```
482011017220120295-27.08
48101224752014070110625451.5124
8200022827TPE035948900001205.5
8200022827TPE03594890000110000000
```